# Introduction to special relativity: Michelson-Morley experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

[image: question]
[image]

I'm trying to solve the first exercise, I've included the reference page for the exercise in the second picture. in the refrence page, the author calculates the time of the round trip for light and assumes light moves through a medium (the ether). (ignore figure 2-12). in the exercise he gives us the same senerio and asks us to caculate the time for the round trip but instead of light moving through the ether we assume light is a particle, and the speed of the particle will also depend on the source (this is a theoretical exercise).I assume T2 should be 2L/c same as if it were at rest, but i am unable to reach that conclusion. for the first equation i have (c+v)t0 = L + v(t0) and t0 = L/c. but i run into a problem with the second equation, the time for the trip back, what im doing is (c+v)tb = L - v(tb), im stuck on this equation, im trying to reach the conlusion that t0 + tb = 2L/c same as if it were at rest. can someone please explain how to solve this exercise, what am i missing here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well to make my question as clear as possible, what is the solution to exercise one?

Comment: I added the "homework-and-exercises" tag to your question. In the future, use this tag for homework and exercises type of questions.

Comment: @yehyafarhat, you are responding to a bot (the "Community" bot). The bot seems to think your question is poorly written. Maybe it thinks this due to the lack of proper punctuation, capitalization and spaces? If you are more careful about the way you write your question it could help you get better answers.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer you should get is actually $$T_2=t_0+t_b=\large \frac{\frac{2L}{c}}{(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})} $$ This is the time light would take to move through the horizontal arm and back (round trip), *if* there was an ether.

Whether light is a particle or wave *here* is not relevant. The point is that light moves with a speed $c$ and if there were an ether, this speed would be $(c-v)$ in one direction (against the ether) and $(c+v)$ in the other direction (with the ether).

Note that $v$ is the speed the apparatus is moving through the so called ether. The fact that if light were a particle or wave will not mean that $v=0$. If there was a difference in time detected, which would mean an interference pattern, between round trips through the horizontal and vertical arms, one could make the argument that there is an ether. But no difference was ever detected. That is, no interference pattern was ever observed, hence no ether.

Why you get that particular expression for $T_2$ becomes a little more obvious when you realize that the speed of the light ray through the arm (length $L$) toward the mirror is $(c-v)$, so that the time it takes to travel from where it is emitted to this mirror is therefore $$t_0=\frac{L}{c-v}\tag1$$  Then by a similar argument, the time the ray takes to return from the mirror is then $$t_b=\frac{L}{c+v}\tag2$$

So the *round trip* time is $$T_2=t_0+t_b=\frac{L}{c-v}+ \frac{L}{c+v}=\frac{L(c+v)+L(c-v)}{c^2-v^2}=\frac{2Lc}{c^2-v^2}= \frac{2L c}{c^2(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})} = \frac{2L}{c}\cdot\frac{1}{{(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}})}=\frac{2L}{c}\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2} \right)^{-1}$$

The result you were trying obtain, comes when we assume that the speed of light is invariant regardless of the motion of the apparatus. This would mean $$c-v \rightarrow c \\ c+v\rightarrow c$$ which then tells us that from equations (1) and (2) $$T_2=t_0+t_b=\frac{L}{c}+\frac{L}{c}=\frac{2L}{c}$$ This is indeed the result obtained, and forms the second postulate of the special theory of relativity, the constancy of the speed of light.

Comment: to rephrase my question, so the first answer you give T2 = t0 + tb = 2l/c / (1-v^2/c^2) is the time of the round trip of the light assuming light moves through the ether correct? and this is what the author calculates from figure 2-11. so to simplify my question as much as possible, I want the time for the round trip of light on the same experiment (figure 2-11) with the apparatus moving to the right with a speed v but instead of light moving through the ether it instead is a particle and its speed also depends on the apparatus it is operating in which moves with the speed of v to the right.

Comment: i guess the way i phrased my question with all the assumptions was not very clear, im not assuming v=0, im assuming that the answer you get when the light acts like a particle (that is the speed of light depends on the source) gives you the same answer as if v=0 which is 2l/c, I'm not sure if this assumption is correct, so in short i just want the answer to the first exercise to see if it is correct or not

Comment: Please see my answer where I have made some edits to address your concerns. Cheers.